# Select a part of a string - Postgresql

Tags: sql, string, postgresql

I have a column with strings like '006_THR'; '1003_ER'; '100_THREE' and i want to put all string before `"_"` in a column and all string after `"_"` in a other column.

```
 col         col1     col2
006_THR      006       THR
1003_ER      1003      ER  
100_THRE     100       THRE
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `split_part()`:

```
select col, split_part(col, '_', 1) as col1, split_part(col, '_', 2) as col2
from t;
```

Comment: I struggled with substring and strpos. I didn't know about split_part. Thank you!

Comment: @Lucian . . . If you like `split_part()` you'll just love `regexp_split_to_table()` and `regexp_split_to_array()`!